# Python in Jupyter Notebooks: 'Table' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have written following code in Jupyter Notebooks for practicing:

```
method=['Take the Bus to Work', 'Drive to Work']
number_coworkers= [12, 15]
coffee=Table().with_columns('Method', method, 'Number of Coworkers', number_coworkers)
total_cups_day = coffee.column(0) * coffee.select("Average Cups of Coffee per Day")
number_cups_day_difference = total_cups_day.item(2) - total_cups_day.item(1)
number_cups_week_difference = number_cups_difference * 7
yearly_cups = number_cups_week_difference * 52
```

I receive following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-aad814252e94> in <module>
      6 method=['Take the Bus to Work', 'Drive to Work']
      7 number_coworkers= [12, 15]
----> 8 coffee=Table().with_columns('Method', method, 'Number of Coworkers', number_coworkers)
      9 total_cups_day = coffee.column(0) * coffee.select("Average Cups of Coffee per Day")
     10 number_cups_day_difference = total_cups_day.item(2) - total_cups_day.item(1)

NameError: name 'Table' is not defined
```

I have seen a similar approach in other Jupyter Notebooks in which Table was not imported so I am unsure about the mistake.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you working with `astropy`? [Table() might be a reference to this](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html)

Comment: You will have to import `Table`. Based on the method `.with_columns()`, it looks like this is in the [`datascience`](http://data8.org/datascience/) package. You can use `from datascience.tables import Table`

Comment: You're missing the lines that start with `import ...`

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install package datascience before you can use the Table(). I used spyder to run your code and did the following :

In the conda terminal :

```
conda install datascience
```

and then in the code add an import :

```
from datascience import *
```

and then you don't see the error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not run `from datascience import *`. It will clutter your namespace. Use `from datascience.tables import Table` or `import datascience` and then `datascience.Table`.

Comment: Please don't share that kind of information as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. As @jakub said, you shouldn't use `import *`.